# Django account lockout

Tags: django, security

Does anyone know of a Django App which can be used to extend django auth and lock accounts if a brute force password guessing attack is mounted?

Ie, an account lockout mechanism that restricts the number of login attempts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lock out users after too many failed login attempts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033287/lock-out-users-after-too-many-failed-login-attempts)

Comment: I guess the possible duplicate Jonny mentions asks it in a more 'stack overflow' appropriate manner, so please use that instead. The answer i got 7 years ago was very useful at the time :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-axes/ is what you are looking for.

Comment: Actually, it isn't quite perfect for my needs - it locks access to an IP address (and user-agent if desired) after a number of failed attempts, and this could be problematic in a situation where multiple users access a site on a NAT'ed network. Ie all users in an office will be locked out if one user goes over the limit!

Answer (score 2):

I created [django-failedloginblocker](https://github.com/alexkuhl/django-failedloginblocker) for this purpose, and used [django-brutebuster](http://code.google.com/p/django-brutebuster/) and, to a lesser extent, django-axes as inspiration.

Comment: both these look useful too - though i used django-axes in the end.

Answer (score 2):

This one is still maintained (2018): https://github.com/kencochrane/django-defender

Answer (score 1):

You can also try http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-lockout/0.1.0

Comment: Thanks @mmrs151 - i'll have a look at that at some point, though i'm not currently working on the project.

Comment: this very simple package worked great for us for a long time but is abandoned with no py3 support