# How to lock a user account for 30 minutes after 5 failed login attempts in Django?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I want to be able to lock user accounts (prevent login) after a defined number of failed logins in a specified period of time. Both the number of login attempts permitted and the time period should be set in the Admin panel.

Example: Lock a user account after 5 failed login attempts in 60 minutes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lock out users after too many failed login attempts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033287/lock-out-users-after-too-many-failed-login-attempts)

Comment: You can try [django-brutebuster](https://github.com/mtrdesign/django-brutebuster)

Comment: Do realize that this also gives attackers a tool to DDoS specific accounts and prevent the legitimate owners from logging in…